# Separate admin site for users

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm kinda new to Django and looking for some advice on a medium sized project. Our in-office admin is one thing, but our users can also log in online and see a similar (more limited, but mostly the same) interface.

The problem is that the users email is the username, and emails don't have to be unique (but passwords must for reasons you understand). Ghetto? Yes. But it's what they expect.

Is it possible to create this second interface as well as deviate away from the traditional username for sign in? Does Django 1.5s custom user model do anything for me here? And is it possible to make use of two user models--one for the admin, and one for our users?

And finally, if I'm heading in the wrong direction entirely, please let me know. This is a follow-up to a question I'd asked previously, but I'd forgotten about some of the details.

EDIT: Much as I hate to do it, I'll just code the member area seperately. More weirdness with the logins has emerged so I think this will be the easiest solution, even if not very DRY.

Comment: yes you are heading in the wrong direction entirely with not unique usernames but unique passwords!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Having two admin interfaces is probably silly. Django's admin supports robust user permissions.
2. Keep username's unique, and use an email authentication backend. This lets users user their email address if they want to. Since, at least in 1.4, email addresses didn't have to be unique, you're in the clear.
3. Here's a simple email auth backend:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
   from django.contrib.admin.models import User

   class EmailAuthBackEnd(ModelBackend):
       def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None,**kwargs):
           try:
               user = User.objects.get(email=email)  
               if user.check_password(password):
                   return user
               return None
           except User.DoesNotExist:
               return None
   ```
4. Add the above to a file called backends.py in one of your apps, then add this to your settings.py:

   ```
   AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS + ('app.backends.EmailAuthBackEnd',)
   ```
5. On the whole unique passwords thing … that's tricky to deal with. You could subclass Django's user model, and change password to a unique string, or you could patch PSQL manually to enforce that constraint. OR you could be lazy, assume passwords will be assigned, assign every user a random username, safe in the knowledge you can always login and 'fix' problem accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you allow users to retain their current credentials (that will be a big plus from a usability point of view), and then adjust what they see depending on where they're coming from. There's lots of methods on django's ModelAdmin that you can override. So on a model by model basis you could do -

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.exclude = []
        if request.META(REMOTE_ADDR) not in [# add list of internal ip's here]
            self.exclude.append('field_to_hide')
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

As in the docs example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form). (also have a look at the list of http headers [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) to get an idea of how you might make your check)

If you want to change the list of objects available on the main admin menu then, look at overriding the [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects), to add your own `get_urls()` method that provides similar functionality to the individual `get_form` method I've suggested above.